# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to web scrape cricket score webiste to get a scorecard.
But i am getting this attribute error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):**
  **File "J:/Python Programs/Web Scraper/ESPN Cric Info.py", line 6, in

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.find(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

File "J:\Python Programs\Web Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1282, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, ****kwargs**)
**
**AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all**'****

My Code Is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19430/scorecard/1187016/india-vs-bangladesh-1st-test-icc-world-test-championship-2019-2021')
soup = BeautifulSoup.find(page.content, 'html.parser')
scorecard = soup.find(id='gp-inning-01')

print(scorecard)
```

It Would Be A Great Help If You Reolve This.

Comment: Please show the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19430/scorecard/1187016/india-vs-bangladesh-1st-test-icc-world-test-championship-2019-2021')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
scorecard = soup.find_all('gp-inning-01')

print(scorecard)
```

Try this

Comment: @Captain.026 if the answer helped you, please up vote the answer. And mark the most helpful answer as the right answer to the question so that others looking for similar issue get quick help.

Answer (score 0):

You made two small mistakes, but your code was almost correct:

- you need to remove `.find` after `BeautifulSoup`, as this line is made just for creating the soup but not searching anything
- you need to use `.text` instead of `.content` when retrieving the request, as BeautifulSoup works with strings rather than bytes.

Here is the final code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19430/scorecard/1187016/india-vs-bangladesh-1st-test-icc-world-test-championship-2019-2021')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
scorecard = soup.find(id='gp-inning-01')

print(scorecard)
```